# tpot: Use multi-output regressors only

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, automl, tpot

I want to use tpot. The data I have includes multi-output continuous variables only (i.e. output shape is: (n_samples, n_output_variables), where all items are floats).

This could be achievable using sklearn's `MultiOutputRegressor` class. But because I have over 100 different output variables, I want to avoid to apply tpot for each individual output.

Now, how can I use tpot to only search for multi-output models? Is there a way to tell tpot that only multi-output models (such as DecisionTree) should be used?

Answer (score 2):

### About regressors with multiple output:

You have a multioutput regression problem. I suggest that you check this answer: [Multi-output regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391637/multi-output-regression).

There are regressors which do natively support multiple output on the target, for example KNeighborsRegressor, DecisionTreeRegressor, GradientBoostingRegressor, ExtraTreesRegressor and RandomForestRegressor. Others (like SGDRegressor, ElasticNetCV, etc...) can be used with multiple output if you use MultiOutputRegressor as you already mentioned.

---

### About TPOT and multiple output regression:

Currently TPOT can be used with all the regressors that support multiple output natively but you have to adjust a file for that because it is not implemented yet, take a look at https://github.com/EpistasisLab/tpot/issues/971. If you want to compare the other regressors (single output) together with MultiOutputRegressor, TPOT will currently let you only choose one at a time. That is you can specify only one of the several algorithms and then search for the best pipeline. Then you could rerun with another algorithm.

Regarding your question about specifying which algorithm you want to search for: first take a look at the official documentation and read the section **Customizing TPOT's operators and parameters**. If you want to just use some specific algorithms, one way to achieve this is to copy the standard TPOT configuration for regression (https://github.com/EpistasisLab/tpot/blob/master/tpot/config/regressor.py), to include it in your code and uncomment (or add) all the algorithms you do not (or do) want to include in your search.