# Find Matrix Closest to Another in Numpy/Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, computer-vision

I have a simple problem.

I have two matrices A and B,

and I want to find a transformation AX that makes AX closest to B in the least squares sense.

i.e. find X such that `X = argmin ||AX -B||` `under 2-norm`.

How can I solve this problem using numpy or scipy?

I tried to search but the only method that is there is lstsq (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) but it finds a linear equation solution involving vector x.

1. How to solve my problem, i.e. find a transformation X for matrix A?
2. Are there any non-linear methods that do this? How is this problem solved in optimization?

Comment: What are the shapes of `A` and `B`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser A is 1000000 x 1024, B is 1000000 x 512

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-output regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391637/multi-output-regression)

Comment: @fizzybear no. its not. its a transformation of a mtrix

Comment: How is that different from a least squares regression mathematically?

Comment: I think `x=np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)[0]` should work